# IllegalArgumentException: com.google.android.gms.common.internal.d.b

Tags: android, google-play-services

Starting about 36 hours ago (Aug 18th) I've noticed a huge spike in the number of exceptions caused by a new exception from Google Play Services:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null reference
   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.d.b(SourceFile:45)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.g.ao.a(SourceFile:60)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.t.b.a(SourceFile:766)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.t.m.run(SourceFile:43)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Few observations:

- Noticed this issue only in one app, but not in others.
- No change was made in the app for the 7 days prior to this issue.
- Both Android 4 & 5, across multiple vendors. No Android 2.3.
- Google Play Services SDK 7.5. It looks like it appears in previous versions too (6.x).

Ideas?

Comment: looks to be an internal issue with google play services

Comment: This is a bug and already reported [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/-RTKFeFvgNQ/lfm0ret_FAAJ). Please wait the engineers fix it.